# function evaluation when limit approaches to infinity

Tags: limits

$$\large \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{\log_2(\log_2 x)}}{x^3}$$

How can I evaluate the above limit?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\log_2(\log_2x)-3}$$  Clearly, $x,\log_2(\log_2x)-3\to\infty$

Comment: @user271017 Please check my edit. I wasn't sure if you meant to have $\dfrac{\log_2(\log_2x)}{3}$ in the exponent or not. (This will have an effect on your answer.)

Comment: Hint:$\forall x>256\,\log_2(\log_2(x))>3$

Comment: so it will be ∞

Comment: this limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

You may write it as, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x^{\log_2(\log_2x)}}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\log_2(\log_2x)-3}.$$ Obviously, $\log_2(\log_2 x)-3$ will tend to infinity as $x\to\infty$, hence the limit is $\infty$.